# Are there any requirements to meet for thumbnail for linksharing?

Tags: thumbnails, facebook-sharer

On the website there are a couple of sites showing details of companies.
Any site has a different -tag declairing a pic as thumbnail for linksharing. (Yes, we also tried the og-meta-tag. but the problem appeared eighter the same way.) We checked all sites with the Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and anything seems to work fine.

However. Not all pics are available in the share-link-dialog. By now we couldn't figure out, what the reason for this behavior may be. Are there any requirements for images to be used here?

An example for a working site: http://www.games-career.com/top_employer_detail.php?id=7
and a "bad" one: http://www.games-career.com/top_employer_detail.php?id=54

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer, but If I host an image, with a domain name, on my personal computer (the domain name redirects to my personal ip), Facebook doesn't recognize images, but it is able to recognize same images on a normal hosting

Hope this info helps you, you may try hosting the image elsewhere